# Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone gives wrong value of timezone

Tags: javascript, datetime

I want to fetch timezone in IANA form for a user using javascript function `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone`. But this function gives incorrect IANA time zone value.

I have used moment.js library's function `moment.tz.guess(true)`. But this also gives same incorrect value. On further analysis, I came to know that this also uses same native JS function `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone` internally

```
var timeZone = moment.tz.guess(); // "America/Los_Angeles"
```

or

```
var timeZone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone; // "America/Los_Angeles"
```

Though the user has set system time to (UTC - 07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada), but still this function gives value as "America/Los_Angeles" which is Pacific standard/daylight timezone. Whereas expected value should be "America/Denver".
Another thing is that this issue started occurring after the daylight savings adjustment came into picture i.e. around mid of March. Beforehand it worked fine. The user is located in Utah, USA.

Can anyone suggest probable root causes of this issue? Also please suggest any workaround, would be very helpful.

Comment: Which browser is the user using?

Comment: Sorry for not following up on this for a long time. Actually, the user uses an application which is based on Nodewebkit and Chromium engine. While debugging the application, it was found that the value of "Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone" came as "America/Los_Angeles" whereas the user is located in Moutain Time zone.It seems that the chromium version of the application is old. This is because, in user's browser version of Chrome, the value of this expresssion comes correctly